# Creating gaussian distributed bitmap image in matlab for Zemax simulation

Tags: image, math, bitmap, matlab

I am a beginner with matlab. And I need it for a very small portion of my project. I am currently working on creating an extended source for a potential optics related project. I need the extended source to be circular or hexagonal in shape and I need the intensity of the source to be Gaussian distributed. My professor told me that I should model the source in Matlab and then import it on Zemax.

Can anyone help me with the matlab part?

Comment: Seems you want for example a disk in {x,y} and gaussian values in {z=F[x,y]} ... ?

Comment: Yea disk, exactly.. I dunno how to go about developing the code.. So if I could get a head start, I'll be fine!

Comment: But ... what do you want as output?

Comment: I need a bitmap image of the extended source!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in Mathematica. Hope you can extrapolate to Matlab:

```
imgSz = 300;

k = Array[0 &, {imgSz, imgSz}]; (* A square image *)

Table[k[[i, j]] = 

   PDF[NormalDistribution[0, imgSz/6],  (* mu, sigma *)

    EuclideanDistance[{i, j}, {imgSz/2, imgSz/2}]], (*distance from centre*)

{i, imgSz}, {j,imgSz}];  (* Table indexes for iteration *)

Image@k // ImageAdjust   (*Show Image*)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Gaussian matrix and impose a hexagonal/circular mask to get the size and shape of the source that you want. You can try

```
%#initialize
N=1000;
x=repmat(linspace(-4,4,N),N,1);y=x';%'#this comment is to fix highlighting in Stackoverflow.
sigma=1;

%#compute a Gaussian matrix
gaussMatrix=exp( -x.^2/(2*sigma^2) - y.^2/(2*sigma^2));

%#create Hexagonal mask
xCenter=0;yCenter=0;%#center
radius=2;%#radius of the inscribed circle, i.e., distance from center to midpoint of side
hexMask=(abs(y-yCenter)<=radius) & ...
    (abs(sqrt(3)/2*(x-xCenter)+1/2*(y-yCenter))<=radius) & ...
    (abs(sqrt(3)/2*(x-xCenter)-1/2*(y-yCenter))<=radius);

figure, imshow(hexMask.*gaussMatrix)

%#create a circular mask
radius=2;
circMask=(abs(y-yCenter).^2+abs(x-xCenter).^2<=radius.^2);
figure, imshow(circMask.*gaussMatrix)
```

The hexagonal source looks like this
[image: Hexagonal source]

and the circular/disk source looks like this

[image: Circular source]

Comment: and just like that I realized how they do fast lighting for objects in 3d games